# Redis migrate command showing NOKEY error

Tags: javascript, sql, database, redis, redis-cli

I am trying to copy all my keys from DB 1 to DB 2 in my redis. I am using following command:

`select 1` to switch to DB 1

`MIGRATE localhost 6380 "" 2 50000 AUTH my_password  COPY KEYS`

This throws `NOKEY` error.
Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't specify any key to be migrated.

Since you used the `KEYS` option, you need to specify keys after this option:

```
MIGRATE localhost 6380 "" 2 50000 AUTH my_password  COPY KEYS key1 key2 key3 ...
```

So in order to migrate keys from one db to another, you need to scan these keys from the source db first.

Also, in your case, you don't need `MIGRATE` command, but the `COPY` command, if you're using Redis 6.2.0 or later.

Try the following one-liner:

```
redis-cli --scan | xargs -I {} redis-cli copy {} {} DB 2
```